# How do I set KUBIE_KUBECONFIG?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have installed [kubie](https://github.com/sbstp/kubie) and have been using it to successfully manage my multi-cluster configs.

However, recently I noticed that my default `KUBECONFIG` and `KUBIE_KUBECONFIG` paths have changed. Now when I try to download a new autopilot cluster config, it disappears.

```
KUBECONFIG=/var/folders/rb/2t5drg9n0f3g_p3y7rnknf_w0000gn/T/kubie-configpAMbHS.yaml
KUBIE_KUBECONFIG=/var/folders/rb/2t5drg9n0f3g_p3y7rnknf_w0000gn/T/kubie-configpAMbHS.yaml
```

I would like to change them back to: `$HOME/.kube/config`.

How can I do this?

**NOTE**: there are no settings in `kubie.yaml` to do this.

Comment: check your .profile and .bashrc and similar if its exported somewhere.

Comment: I checked those, and they don't seem to be set there. Its puzzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I followed the instructions in the README.md - section Settings - https://github.com/sbstp/kubie/blob/master/README.md#settings and now `echo $KUBECONFIG` shows the right paths.

```
# yaml
# Force kubie to use a particular shell, if unset detect shell currently in use.
# Possible values: bash, dash, fish, xonsh, zsh
# Default: unset
shell: bash

# Configure where to look for kubernetes config files.
configs:

    # Include these globs.
    # Default: values listed below.
    include:
        - ~/.kube/config
        - ~/.kube/*.yml
        - ~/.kube/*.yaml
        - ~/.kube/configs/*.yml
        - ~/.kube/configs/*.yaml
        - ~/.kube/kubie/*.yml
        - ~/.kube/kubie/*.yaml

    # Exclude these globs.
    # Default: values listed below.
    # Note: kubie's own config file is always excluded.
    exclude:
        - ~/.kube/kubie.yaml

# Prompt settings.
prompt:
    # Disable kubie's custom prompt inside of a kubie shell. This is useful
    # when you already have a prompt displaying kubernetes information.
    # Default: false
    disable: true

    # When using recursive contexts, show depth when larger than 1.
    # Default: true
    show_depth: true

    # When using zsh, show context and namespace on the right-hand side using RPS1.
    # Default: false
    zsh_use_rps1: false

    # When using fish, show context and namespace on the right-hand side.
    # Default: false
    fish_use_rprompt: false

    # When using xonsh, show context and namespace on the right-hand side.
    # Default: false
    xonsh_use_right_prompt: false

# Behavior
behavior:
    # Make sure the namespace exists with `kubectl get namespaces` when switching
    # namespaces. If you do not have the right to list namespaces, disable this.
    # Default: true
    validate_namespaces: true

    # Enable or disable the printing of the 'CONTEXT => ...' headers when running
    # `kubie exec`.
    # Valid values:
    #   auto:   Prints context headers only if stdout is a TTY. Piping/redirecting
    #           kubie output will auto-disable context headers.
    #   always: Always prints context headers, even if stdout is not a TTY.
    #   never:  Never prints context headers.
    # Default: auto
    print_context_in_exec: auto
```